# SaaS Application with Azure AD authentication as MS Teams App with App Studio

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

My company is using this service Aha! Ideas for internal idea-sharing. Everything is set up correctly with Aha! and the page site loads and requests the email for the user. Once they put it in the Microsoft credentials from the host machine so an SSO and they are redirected to the secure page. On machines where the user has not authenticated against our domain on the workstation, they are redirected to the Microsoft login and after they login, the user is redirected to the site.

So Great!! that is all working perfectly.

Now, I go into App Studio in Microsoft Teams and set up the site to load as an App in the Sidebar. I have added the main URL as a tab, I have set up the Valid Domains and included login.microsoftonline.com and I have set ADD App ID to the one used in the SAML2 setup of Aha!.

When I load the app I get the page requesting my email, this is from Aha!, and when I submit it should use SSO from Teams to log me in. I am logged in to Teams using my company Microsoft Account. At a minimum, it should redirect to the login.microsoftonline.com and request my username and password. Instead, I get nothing but a blank page.

Anyone have any ideas as to why it's not working, or what I might have done wrong?

Comment: The page which you are trying to load inside the team is Iframable?

Answer (score 0):

'SSO' in the truest sense with Teams -definitely- won't work - it requires changes to the app itself, which you don't control, but even aside from that, depending on how the app ends up doing it's authentication, this still might not work, as you're seeing. Is there maybe a chance Aha! is working on Teams integration?